# Aligning 3 images with a title and description underneath

Tags: html, css

Trying to get my three figures to align such as: image with a heading and description below each of the 3 images. This currently works, however I'm having height issues. I.e. if the `<p>` descriptions are different lengths then figures will start at different points, therefore the frames are no longer aligned with each others anymore. I looked back at older posts, and found some sort of display:flex solution but I didn't really understand/like it. Any suggestions?

HTML

```
<section class = "container site-repairs">


    <figure>
    <img src = "repair1.png"/>

    <h3>Rof Repair</h3>
    <p> Concrete, Slate, Felt or Fibreglass Cormack Roofing can repair any roofing problems you have
        Skylights Extra lighting can make all the difference in your home please contact 
    </p>
    </figure>

    <figure>
    <img src = "repair2.png"/>
    <h3>Skylights</h3>
    <p> 
        Extra lighting can make all the difference in your home please contact us to find out more
    </p>
    </figure>

    <figure>
    <img src = "repair3.png"/>
    <h3>Gutters/Facias</h3>
    <p> Gutters and Facia boards play an important part in keeping your home dry</p>
    </figure>


</section>
```

CSS

```
.site-repairs{
    text-align:center;
    padding:0;
}

.site-repairs figure{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0;

}

.site-repairs img{

}
.site-repairs h3{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-top:5px;
}
.site-repairs p{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:131px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    font-size:13px;
    margin-top:15px;
    color:grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all 3 of your images and description, you can wrap them and set the display as flex so you can align them centered. After that, you can put each of your images with their description in 3 container's which will also be display flex and you can set their flex-direction as column so you can have them one next to another and of course align them centered.

Comment: is that the easiest way? seems rather complex for such a small task

Comment: Flex is kind of complex, but for the long run, it's very powerful and can be very useful for what you do in the future.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when you resize your page, nothing is aligned anymore. Am i wrong?

Comment: Your solution worked, though I don't entirely understand it. I'll take a look at flex later tonight, looks rather useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Making the position of site-repairs class relative and the content in it absolute solves the problem. Making the position: absolute for figure will align all the elements and adding margin to each element will fix each figure position.

HTML:

```
<figure style = "margin-left: 20%">
<img src = "https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/code-flat.png"/>

<h3>Rof Repair</h3>
<p> Concrete, Slate, Felt or Fibreglass Cormack Roofing can repair any roofing problems you have
    Skylights Extra lighting can make all the difference in your home please contact 
</p>
</figure>

<figure style = "margin-left: 40%">
<img src = "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/luchesa-vol-9/128/Html-512.png"/>
<h3>Skylights</h3>
<p> 
    Extra lighting can make all the difference in your home please contact us to find out more
</p>
</figure>

<figure style = "margin-left: 60%">
<img src = "http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/caribbean-blue/code-optimization-2-xxl.png"/>
<h3>Gutters/Facias</h3>
<p> Gutters and Facia boards play an important part in keeping your home dry</p>
</figure>
```

CSS:

```
 .site-repairs{

    padding:0;
  position: relative;
}

.site-repairs figure{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0;
  position: absolute;

}


.site-repairs h3{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-top:5px;
}
.site-repairs p{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:131px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    font-size:13px;
    margin-top:15px;
    color:grey;
}
img {
  width: 40px;
}
```

I've used some random images for display.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!